# How to View Next Image in An Array Using Index/Integer - iPhone Dev

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

Right,

I've got an array which looks like so:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad;
{
    imageArray = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"], 
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"], 
                  nil] retain];
}
```

And I have an IBAction that is triggered when a button is clicked like so:

```
-(IBAction)next {

    UIImage *img = [imageArray objectAtIndex:0];
    [imageView setImage:img];   

}
```

The problem is that when the button is clicked, it's only ever choosing the object at index 0 (obviously!).  What I want to know is how do I define the index with an integer in the .h file, and use it in the IBAction so that whenever I click the next button it will go to the next image in the array rather than to index 0 every time?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int current_image_index = 0;

-(IBAction)next {

    if (current_image_index + 1 == [imageArray count])
          current_image_index = 0;
    UIImage *img = [imageArray objectAtIndex:current_image_index];
    [imageView setImage:img]; 
    current_image_index++;



}
```

Comment: That code builds okay, which is better than mine, but it still only shows the first image in the array no matter how many times I click next.

Comment: @Ian : @ennuikiller Code look me working so couple of queries, where did you declare "current_image_index" ? and At which place in your code default value (0) get assigned  to "current_image_index",

Comment: @Jhaliya I am still getting used to this stuff so I probably haven't defined stuff properly.  current_image_index I defined in my .h file using: NSNumber *current_image_index.  Then I have int current_image_index = 0; in the .m file outside of any code blocks.  With this, the app crashes when I click the button a second time to get to the next image in the array